# Registering types from a boost mpl vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

```
std::string a= "a";
std::string b= "b";
std::string c= "c";

typedef mpl::vector<EasyFixEngineA,EasyFixEngineB,EasyFixEngineC> vecType;

RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, mpl::at_c<vecType,0>::type>    registerA( a); 
RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, mpl::at_c<vecType,1>::type,>   registerB( b);  
RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, mpl::at_c<vecType,2>::type>    registerC( c);
```

How can I generate automatically the last 3 lines by using boost::mpl ?
By automatically I mean don't have to repeat 3 times the "same" line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility utilizing [mpl::for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html):

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>

struct EasyFixEngineA { static const char* const name() { return "a"; } };
struct EasyFixEngineB { static const char* const name() { return "b"; } };

struct Registrator {
    template<class T> void operator()(T t) {
        RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, T> dummy(T::name());
    }
};

// ...
typedef boost::mpl::vector<EasyFixEngineA,EasyFixEngineB> Engines;
boost::mpl::for_each<Engines>(Registrator());
```

If the instantiation of `T` isn't suitable in your case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053436/is-it-possible-to-iterate-an-mplvector-at-run-time-without-instantiating-the-ty).

Comment: I can't use lambda expression instead of functor here ?

Comment: @Guillaume: You can't template lambdas, so you need to use a functor with a templated member or a template function to get the actual types from `for_each`.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche Not true anymore, C++14 added generic lambdas

Answer (score 1):

The very short answer is that you can't.

Indeed there are three different things :
– compile-time execution (aka. metaprogramming) which is done with MPL. They only work on type definitions
– run-time execution (aka. usual programming) which is plain C++ (at that point all the types are defined)
– variable declarations

You want to use MPL (compile-time) to generate some C++ code (variable declaration) and do some run-time (variables initialization).

Maybe you want to look at boost::fusion (fusion means combining compile-time and run-time operations).
If you declare your three variables in a boost::fusion, and also you three strings, then you could use boost::fusion::transform. But i'm not sure if it's what you want